# How do I escape an asterisk in Silktest XPaths?

Tags: xpath, silktest

I have a UI element that contains an asterisk. Reading the [Silktest XPath docs](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.classic.doc%2FSTCLASSIC-F57B051C-XPATH-SAMPLES.html) I find that `*` is a special character which matches everything (wildcard).

How do I escape it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The support says:

> You can only escape the * with a ?. This will only work for single characters.

Comment: This is very sad news